# renaming google's spreadsheet automatically by (an excel) formula

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets

I'm trying to make Google's Spreadsheet do something that I don't know how to do.

Basically I want that it copies the text on specific cells and put it automatically on the filename.

So if I have: 
"111" on A1
"222" on A2
"333" on A3
And I put the "magic formula" only on A1 and A3, it automatically renames the file "111 333"

Comment: You need to use AppScript for this. Read up on the [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) class and use [rename](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#rename(String)) or [renameActiveSheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#renameActiveSheet(String)).

Comment: I'm having troubles making this work.. how should I use it?

Comment: I want the name of the document be renamed by taking the values of a few cells. Not only one.

Comment: Yes, you can do that with [Appscript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets). Please refer to the links I previously gave and the docs to get started.

Comment: I need help if you can please.. I'm not a programmer and I don't know how to do this. Or I have to pay to get this thing done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your spreadsheet, Tools -> Script Editor

```
function onOpen()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var a1 = ss.getRange("A1").getValue();
  var a3 = ss.getRange("A3").getValue();
  var name = a1+" "+a3;
  ss.rename(name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the code Andy! It only worked partially though. I only got A1 cell on the name (the A3 was missing) EDIT IT WORKED THANKS

Comment: If I wanted to add another cell I do like this?: var name = a1+" "+a3 "+a4;

Comment: Yes, `var name = a1+" "+a3+" "+a4;` The quotations are just to add spaces. Make sure you also actually get the data for a4. `var a4 = ss.getRange("A4").getValue();`